# Enable subtitle stream play by default with ffmpeg

Tags: vlc-media-player

Can ffmpeg create a movie with a subtitle track flagged for automatic visibility?

For example in VLC I have to manually enable a subtitle track from the Subtitle menu. It would be great if subtitles would show up without any intervention.

I've found this on stackoverflow:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -i in.srt -c copy -disposition:s:0 default out.mkv
```

But it selects the default subtitle track from multiple tracks it does not make any subtitle visible on movie start.

Comment: I think It's not related to ffmpeg, It's related to VLC itself. i muxed subtitle onto mkv with command `ffmpeg -i film.mkv -i sub.srt -c copy -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1:s out.mkv` and it was showed by default on KMP but not on VLC

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought it was something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MP4Box 0.6.2-DEV-rev453](//gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/downloads/gpac-nightly-builds) (May 2016) or higher to do this:

```
mp4box -add xr.mp4 -add xr.en.srt:txtflags=0xC0000000 -new ya.mp4
```

This will mark the subtitle stream in the output file as forced. **However**,
this mark will only be recognized starting with these versions of programs:

- [MPC-HC 1.7.10.207](//nightly.mpc-hc.org) (May 2016)
- [VLC 3.0.0-20161101](//nightlies.videolan.org) (Nov 2016)

---

I have seen mentions to [this post](//ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2015-January/167371.html) on the FFmpeg mailing list about a
patch that implements disposition for FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i xr.mp4 -i xr.en.srt -c copy -c:s mov_text -disposition:s forced ya.mp4
```

However after having tried it with both "forced" and "default", the subtitles
marked by FFmpeg are not recognized as forced by either MPC-HC or VLC.

---

To respond to the comment, here is a test with MP4Box 0.7.0 (Apr 2017) and
VLC 3.0.0-20170926 (Sep 2017). Note more recent VLC versions are having a
crashing problem, even on videos without subtitles. Using this file:

```
youtube-dl --write-auto-sub --format 18 --output xr.mp4 kcs82HnguGc
ffmpeg -i xr.en.vtt xr.en.srt
mp4box -add xr.mp4 -add xr.en.srt:txtflags=0xC0000000 -new ya.mp4
```

Result:

> [image: sub]

Answer (score 0):

It's related to VLC.
You can enable automatic visibility of subtitle in VLC by writing the word `any` in **Tools ==> Preferences ==> Subtitles/OSD ==> Preferred subtitle language**